# The complex Hilbert space $L^2$ can identified with $L^2 \times L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and denote $I:=(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Consider the square-integrable function spaces:
$$
L^2(I, \mathbb{C}):=\left\{ f: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \; ; \; \int_I |f(x)|^2 \; dx<\infty \right\}
$$
endowed with the usual inner product
$$
(f,g)_{L^2(I, \mathbb{C})}=\int_I f(x) \cdot \overline{g(x)} \; dx,\; \forall \; f,g \in L^2(I, \mathbb{C}). \tag{1}
$$
And
$$
L^2(I, \mathbb{R}):=\left\{ f: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \; ; \; \int_I (f(x))^2 \; dx< \infty \right\}
$$
equipped with the usual inner product defined in analogous way as in $(1)$.

**Question.** Since $\mathbb{C}$ can be idenfied with $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is $\mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R}^2$, we can we can identify $L^2(I, \mathbb{C}) \equiv L^2(I, \mathbb{R}) \times L^2(I, \mathbb{R})$?

My question is in the sense that a function $f \in L^2(I, \mathbb{C})$ has the form $f=f_1+if_2$ for some $f_1,f_2 \in L^2(I, \mathbb{R})$, whereas a function $g \in L^2(I, \mathbb{R}) \times L^2(I, \mathbb{R})=: \big(L^2(I, \mathbb{R})\big)^2$ has the form $g=(g_1,g_2)$ also for some $g_1,g_2 \in L^2(I, \mathbb{R})$. So,  due to $ \mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R}^2$, can I write $f=f_1+if_2\equiv (f_1,f_2) \in \big(L^2(I, \mathbb{R})\big)^2$? Are there any problems with regard to inner products (or norms)?

Comment: No prblems at all if you define the norm on the product as $\|(f_1,f_2)\|=\sqrt {\|f_1\|^{2}+\|f_2\|^{2}}$.

Comment: I think you want your $L^2$ to be $<\infty$, not $<0$.   As $<0$ the space is empty!

Comment: @Alan Yes, $<\infty$. I fixed it. Thanks!